# Terraform github_repository from private template

Tags: github, terraform, github-api

I am trying to create a `github_repository` resource from a private template, declared like this:

```
resource "github_repository" "source_code" {

  name = "test"
  template {
    owner      = "me"
    repository = "template-repository" // this is a private repository
  }
  visibility = "private"
}
```

***me** and **template-repository** are example values*.

When I run `terraform apply`, I get the following failure:

```
╷
│ Error: POST https://api.github.com/repos/me/template-repository/generate: 404 Not Found []
│
│   with module.test.module.repository.github_repository.source_code,
│   on modules\serverless_api_repository\main.tf line 1, in resource "github_repository" "source_code":
│    1: resource "github_repository" "source_code" {
│
╵
```

When I set `TF_LOG` to `DEBUG`, I can see the contents of that `POST` request.

```
2021-11-29T10:34:30.245-0600 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-github_v4.18.1.exe: ---[ REQUEST ]---------------------------------------
2021-11-29T10:34:30.245-0600 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-github_v4.18.1.exe: POST /repos/me/template-repository/generate HTTP/1.1
2021-11-29T10:34:30.245-0600 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-github_v4.18.1.exe: Host: api.github.com
2021-11-29T10:34:30.245-0600 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-github_v4.18.1.exe: User-Agent: go-github
2021-11-29T10:34:30.245-0600 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-github_v4.18.1.exe: Content-Length: 66
2021-11-29T10:34:30.245-0600 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-github_v4.18.1.exe: Accept: application/vnd.github.baptiste-preview+json
2021-11-29T10:34:30.245-0600 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-github_v4.18.1.exe: Content-Type: application/json
2021-11-29T10:34:30.245-0600 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-github_v4.18.1.exe: Accept-Encoding: gzip
2021-11-29T10:34:30.245-0600 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-github_v4.18.1.exe:
2021-11-29T10:34:30.245-0600 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-github_v4.18.1.exe: {
2021-11-29T10:34:30.245-0600 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-github_v4.18.1.exe:  "name": "test",
2021-11-29T10:34:30.245-0600 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-github_v4.18.1.exe:  "owner": "",
2021-11-29T10:34:30.245-0600 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-github_v4.18.1.exe:  "description": "",
2021-11-29T10:34:30.245-0600 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-github_v4.18.1.exe:  "private": true
2021-11-29T10:34:30.245-0600 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-github_v4.18.1.exe: }
2021-11-29T10:34:30.245-0600 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-github_v4.18.1.exe:
2021-11-29T10:34:30.245-0600 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-github_v4.18.1.exe: -----------------------------------------------------
```

The problem is that terraform is not adding my OAuth 2.0 token to the headers for this request. I should see `Authorization: token ghp_<the actual token>` as one of the headers, like terraform does for normal REST calls. This token does have the `repo` claim, and I was able to try out this request in hoppscotch successfully by just adding that header. Is this a bug in terraform, or am I missing some kind of configuration?

For the record, I have declared a `github` provider with the appropriate OAuth 2.0 token:

```
provider "github" {
  token = "ghp_<secret ooh...>"
}
```

The provider version is `~> 4.18.0`.

I have verified that terraform can create repositories directly. It only fails when I try to create from private templates.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your private **template-repository** as a template repository. Just follow the instructions in
[Creating a template repository](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/creating-a-template-repository) and then try again with `terraform apply`.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, just guessing by the documentation.

If the [Github Terraform provider docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs#owner) are to be trusted:

> owner - (Optional) [...] When not provided and a token is available, the individual user account owning the token will be used.

So I think you might be missing the `owner` parameter to the provider.

Comment: When I tested this out on hoppscotch, it worked without providing `owner`.